# Sitecore-SXA Search results and facets

Tags: sitecore-sxa

We have a requirement to group the results within Search results page. We are using SXA Search implementation. As SXA Search doesn't support the grouping of the results OOB, we created a custom rendering as mentioned in this article: https://www.switchit.com/blog/sitecore/extending-sitecore-sxa-search-results.aspx

We are now able to get the results grouped by category/template as per requirement.

But the problem we are running into is the following: We also need couple of facets on the page. So we used checklist facet to display the cateogories. But when when we click on the facet, the search results part (created with the custom rendering )  is not refreshing. We do see the ajax call from the filter click, and if we check with that URL, we are seeing JSON data. But somehow the result area doesn't get refreshed.

Any ideas/suggestions as to how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

As you have created a custom rendering for the search results, you will need to write the code that uses the JSON results and refreshes your custom rendering. You cannot expect the ootb javascript to work with you customization..  I would check the ootb javascript and use that as example to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use the **signature** on all your search components if you have dependency between them.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, please try to explain a little bit your answer.